# mysql select query help like in shown pictures

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in mysql like shown below in picture 1:

[image: SOURCE TABLE]

Can you tell me how to make a select query which result will be like in picture 2
and to select faster:

[image: result]

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes that you have a unique constraint on `STUD_ID,CLASS,LESSON`

```
SELECT STUD_ID, 
       CLASS,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LESSON='MATH' THEN MARK END) AS MATH,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LESSON='CHEM' THEN MARK END) AS CHEM,

        ...
        AVG(MARK) AS `Avg`
GROUP BY STUD_ID, CLASS
```

(If you really need that `ID` column that doesn't relate to any ids you can use [the technique from here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/)).

Comment: think that there are over 100.000 rows in this table. Will this query be faster?